# Can we have two dimensional generic list?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, ilist

Can we have a two dimensional generic list

```
IList<IList<AbcAuditDto>>
```

Is it a good approach ?

Comment: We are passing geenric lists from Data Access Layer to Business Object layer. But in one case I need to have a two dimensional list.So is it a good approach to pass "IList<IList<AbcAuditDto>>"...Or should I prefer "IList<List<AbcAuditDto>> "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely possible. Whether it's a "good approach" or not depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: +1 for typing almost exactly what I typed at exactly the same time. :)

Comment: Lol. Two second difference, that's hilarious.

Comment: No kidding. I couldn't have copy/pasted that fast - let alone edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have a list of lists. Whether this is a good approach depends heavily on the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: We are passing geenric lists from Data Access Layer to Business Object layer. But in one case I need to have a two dimensional list.So is it a good approach to pass "IList<IList<AbcAuditDto>>"...Or should I prefer "IList<List<AbcAuditDto>> "

Comment: I would use the IList<IList<AbcAuditDto>> over the IList<List<AbcAuditDto>>. You might also want to re-think your design and pass back something more meaningful. Create an class representing a collection of audit objects. I'm assuming that there is some reason that you can't pass back an IList<AbcAuditDto> that is a unioned collection of all the contained lists.

Answer (score 0):

By using a list of lists of something, you make it more difficult for other developers to see the data type and understand its use.  If you are passing the data to other classes, then this is even more important.

I would recommend creating a new class in place of using nested lists.  This way you can name each dimension of your list of lists and it is easier to work with.